# Es posible la paginación de datos dentro de un Detal View en Django?

Tags: python, django, paginación

Quería saber si es posible paginar datos dentro de un Detail View en Django, les cuento a grandes rasgos, resulta que tenemos una tabla proyectos la cual tiene a ella asociada trabajadores, materiales y servicios, en mi Detail View valga la redundancia veo el detalle de el proyecto seleccionado pero a la vez muestro en el mismo los trabajadores, materiales y servicios que tiene asociado mediante 3 tablas, quisiera saber si es posible paginar estas tablas ya que el paginate_by no funciona dentro del Detail View.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te informes de la manera adecuada de formular una pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: Si se puede, pero tienes que crear el *paginator* manualmente en el `DetailView`, yo lo haría en el método `get_context_data`, y  de una ves extiendo el contexto con el *paginator*.

Answer (score 0):

En un curso que realize, para paginar se uso el siguiente codigo:

```
class PostsFeedView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
"""Return all published posts."""

template_name = 'posts/feed.html'
model = Post
ordering = ('-created',)
paginate_by = 30
context_object_name = 'posts'
```

Y funcionaba bastante bien, a lo mejor te sirve.